# React-NodeGUI based packed App doesn't execute on double click in linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, desktop-application

I'm using `react-nodegui` for building an desktop app.. So far it works perfectly fine in the development environment. But after packaging the application for release using `nodegui-packer`, even after a successful build the `.appimage` or `AppRun` file of `./deploy/linux/build/<app-name>/` directory. But **works fine** if I execute them from a **terminal** or **commandline**

#### Commands I used to build

```sh
$ npm run build
$ npx nodegui-packer -p ./dist
```